# SQL Server : PATINDEX using pattern

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am using `PATINDEX` to replace stray characters in string (column in my table).

```
select PATINDEX('%[^A-Z,a-z0-9 -()&_/\.]%', 'This has a stray character$')
```

I am puzzled as to why the result is 0 (I am expecting 27): `$` is not in the pattern that I want to keep. Any insights?

Comment: What are stray characters?

Comment: Any character NOT in the pattern that I have specified: the $ is NOT in the pattern,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The thing is that dash `-` is used in pattern matching. So you have to escape it:

```
select PATINDEX('%[^A-Z,a-z0-9 \-()&_/\.]%', 'This has a stray character$')
```

Comment: Well spotted; thank you - this solves my problem. However, if I substitute £ for $ in my original post (i.e. without escaping - in the pattern), I do get 27 - seems to be something about $.

Comment: I don't think so. You may just encounter unreliable behaviour. I don't think it is because of dollar sign.

Answer (score 0):

I would escape all special character:

```
select PATINDEX('%[^A-Z,a-z0-9 \-\(\)\&\_\/\\\.]%', 'This has a stray character$')
```

<kbd>**[`LiveDemo`](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/390838)**</kbd>